# Excel 2007 and C# Disabling all prompts

Tags: c#, excel, page-break

i implemented a c# program which opens several excel files to batch convert them to PDF.
Now i have a problem with the page break preview prompt which shows up on a few excel files and stops the whole batch conversion.

[image: Page Breaks Preview]

I tried to solve the problem in disabling all prompts and deleting all pagebreaks but it doesnt work:

```
    excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
                    {
                        ScreenUpdating = false,
                        DisplayAlerts = false,
                        Visible = false,
                        ShowMenuFloaties = false,
                        ShowWindowsInTaskbar = false                           
                    };
        if (excelWorkbook != null)
                    {
                        //clear page breaks
                        foreach (Worksheet ws in excelWorkbook.Worksheets)
                        {                        
                            ws.ResetAllPageBreaks();
                        }
    }
```

Even the checkbox "Do not show this dialog again" does not work. As soon as i reopen the same file the prompt shows up again.

Who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. I installed an Add-in several weeks ago and somehow this Add-in caused this prompt to show up. After deinstalling it it's working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot this:

> excelApp.Visible = false;